# Will the noise from a voltage regulator interfere with IR LEDs and receivers on an Atmega328? (Arduino Uno sketch)

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, voltage-level, ir

I have a project which uses an IR LED and receiver to communicate with other Arduinos. I am using the Atmega328 out of the Uno, rather than the whole Arduino board and I need it to be battery-powered, so I need to use a voltage regulator to maintain 5V to the chip.

I want to avoid a linear regulator if I can, as they are inefficient, but I'm worried that the other types will cause too much noise on the output and it will interfere with the IR communication.

Should I be concerned about this or am I making a fuss about nothing, I can always use a linear one if I need to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on the switching frequency of the regulator. If it coincides with the IR carrier frequency, or a multiple thereof, then possibly.

Comment: If in doubt add some suitable filtering.

Answer (score 1):

I bought a switching mode voltage regulator (buck-boost) to test it and it works fine, I put a 10uF capacitor across the output to reduce noise but that was just a precaution - I don't know if it was necessary.